# no module - gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am making a helloworld application in Django/python to test gunicorn integration. I have a directory and I have a start.sh file. I want to run a gunicorn server that will host a testing page. I am getting the following error:

```
omars-mbp:helloworld omarjandali$ ../start.sh
Starting Gunicorn.
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1238] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1238] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1238)
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1238] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1241] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1241
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1241] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1241] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1241)
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1242] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1242
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1242] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
[2017-11-13 22:10:43 -0800] [1242] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1242)
[2017-11-13 22:10:44 -0800] [1238] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-11-13 22:10:44 -0800] [1238] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Here is my start.sh file and an image of my directory:

```
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn helloworld.wsgi:application \
  --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
  --workers 3
```

I am executing the code from the helloworld folder with the wsgi file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start gunicorn from the `helloworld` folder you need to modify your script like this:

```
echo Starting Gunicorn.
exec gunicorn wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```